# Could not GET gradle-7.4.2.pom Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

When I **sync my project with gradle files**, I receive this error, I searched a lot but I couldn't figure it out.
Error Line:
`Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden`

I tried to Sync my project with gradle files and I wanted to work with my project after awhile, but I end up in the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jcenter was deprecated some time ago, remove any references to `jcenter()` from your build files.

Typical `settings.gradle.kts` should look like...

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Or just replacing `jcenter()` with `google()` and `mavenCentral()` should be a good starting point.

Comment: I changed jcenter() with google() and mavenCentral() and again it says:   `Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.  
Searched in the following locations:  
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom  
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom  
Required by:  
    project :  
Add google Maven repository and sync project  
Open File`

Comment: what is the `settings.gradle.kts` ?

Comment: also I can't check for update, it says:   `Connection failed (Request failed with status code 404). Please check network connection and try again.`